# Why does my SQL query not work when I use join?

Tags: sql, join

I need help with this simple SQL query, I don't understand where the problem is:

```
SELECT id 
FROM transaction 
JOIN users, link ON transaction.id = link.transaction_id 
                 AND link.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.id = 2;
```

When I run it, I get this error:

> ERROR: near "transaction": syntax error

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS For code questions give a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I rewrite your query as

```
SELECT ID 
  FROM TRANSACTION
  INNER JOIN LINK
    ON TRANSACTION.ID = LINK.TRANSACTION_ID
  INNER JOIN USERS
    ON LINK.USER_ID = USERS.ID
  WHERE USERS.ID = 2
```

the only error I get is

```
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

This is because you have the field ID defined on multiple tables. You'll need to clearly identify just which ID you want returned, as in

```
SELECT TRANSACTION.ID 
  FROM TRANSACTION
  INNER JOIN LINK
    ON TRANSACTION.ID = LINK.TRANSACTION_ID
  INNER JOIN USERS
    ON LINK.USER_ID = USERS.ID
  WHERE USERS.ID = 2
```

Also note that LINK and TRANSACTION are both reserved words in Oracle. In this particular case it doesn't cause problems, but in other circumstances it might. It's a good idea to consult [a list of reserved words and keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Oracle-SQL-Reserved-Words-and-Keywords.html#GUID-6A07BB21-AD82-4B47-80FA-9B1141CC23C2) to prevent problems.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2e1466a4da5b2d458b16d10368ce1e15)

Comment: Thanks I think the problem was due to the names so I fixed it .

Answer (score 1):

Use `JOIN` correctly, and it will work:

```
SELECT id 
FROM transaction JOIN
     link
     ON transaction.id = link.transaction_id  JOIn
     users 
     ON link.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.id = 2;
```

Your query may have other problems, such as `id` being ambiguous, but that is not the question you are asking.

The problem with your query is the scoping around commas in the `FROM` clause.  The comma prevents the later `ON` clause from seeing the table.  This is the one way that `,` differs from `CROSS JOIN`.

Of course, the simple rule and best practice is:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: So I tried but but I have the same issue : SELECT * FROM transaction JOIN link ON transaction.id = link.transaction_id JOIN users ON link.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 2
ERROR: near "transaction": syntax error

Comment: @MattéoMenager . . . `transaction` is probably a reserved word in the (unspecified) database that you are using.  It *is* a SQL keyword.  You need to escape the name or choose a better name for the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming **transaction, users** and **link** as 3 separate tables, I am getting id from transaction table, you can change as per your requirement.

Here is the correct syntax for JOIN:

```
SELECT a.id 
FROM transaction a
JOIN users ON transaction.id = link.transaction_id 
JOIN link ON link.user_id = users.id 
WHERE users.id = 2;
```